# multi-file upload cannot submitted when using jquery append

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to generate form input file(s) using jquery, but i have problem when uploading the forms, only one input-file submitted, the form from jquery-append not submitted
my jquery code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var i =$('#gbr_area span').size() + 1;
    $('#btnAdd').click(function() {
        if(i<6)
        {
            $('#gbr_area').append("<span><input type='radio' name='logo_produk' value='"+i+"'>logo produk ke "+i+"<input type='file' name='gambar["+i+"]' size='5'><input type='button' id='btnDel' value='hapus'><br></span>");
            i++;
        }
        return false;
    });

    $("#btnDel").live('click', function(event) {
        $(this).parent().remove();
        return false;
    });
});
```

and this html code:

```
<form action='/add_save/' method='post' enctype='multipart/form-data'><tr>
    <td>
        <div id='gbr_area'>
        <span>
            <input type='radio' name='logo_produk' value='1'>logo produk ke 1
            <input type='file' name='gambar[1]' size='5'>
            <input type='button' id='btnDel' value='hapus'><br>
        </span>
        </div>
        <input type='button' id='btnAdd' value='tambah gambar lain'>
    </td>
    <td>
        <input type='submit' value='add'>
    </td>";
</tr></form>
```

Comment: Can you include the server side code that deals with the submit ?

Answer (score 1):

I can't say specifically without seeing the server code that handles the upload, however, after cleaning up your code a little and testing it in jsfiddle, the javascript creates a form like:

```
<form action="/action/" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <div id="gbr_area">
    <span>
      <input type="radio" name="logo_produk" value="1">logo produk ke 1
      <input type="file" name="gambar[1]" size="5">
      <input type="button" id="btnDel" value="hapus"><br>
    </span>
    <span>
      <input type="radio" name="logo_produk" value="2">logo produk ke 2
      <input type="file" name="gambar[2]" size="5">
      <input type="button" id="btnDel" value="hapus"><br>
    </span>
    <span>
      <input type="radio" name="logo_produk" value="3">logo produk ke 3
      <input type="file" name="gambar[3]" size="5">
      <input type="button" id="btnDel" value="hapus"><br>
    </span>
    <span>
      <input type="radio" name="logo_produk" value="4">logo produk ke 4
      <input type="file" name="gambar[4]" size="5">
      <input type="button" id="btnDel" value="hapus"><br>
    </span>
    <span>
      <input type="radio" name="logo_produk" value="5">logo produk ke 5
      <input type="file" name="gambar[5]" size="5">
      <input type="button" id="btnDel" value="hapus"><br>
    </span>
  </div>
  <input type="submit" value="add">
</form>
```

When I submit this form, I see the following go over the wire (data omitted for brevity):

```
POST /action/ HTTP/1.1
Content-Length:1320
Content-Type:multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundaryzBEm8aSzMRApGfYS
Origin:http://fiddle.jshell.net
Referer:http://fiddle.jshell.net/_display/

------WebKitFormBoundaryzBEm8aSzMRApGfYS
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="gambar[1]"; filename="hello.cmi"
Content-Type: application/octet-stream

<data>
------WebKitFormBoundaryzBEm8aSzMRApGfYS
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="gambar[2]"; filename="hello.cmo"
Content-Type: application/octet-stream

<data>
------WebKitFormBoundaryzBEm8aSzMRApGfYS
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="gambar[3]"; filename="hello.cmx"
Content-Type: application/octet-stream

<data>
------WebKitFormBoundaryzBEm8aSzMRApGfYS
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="gambar[4]"; filename="hello.ml"
Content-Type: text/x-ocaml

<data>
------WebKitFormBoundaryzBEm8aSzMRApGfYS
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="gambar[5]"; filename=""
Content-Type: application/octet-stream

<data>
------WebKitFormBoundaryzBEm8aSzMRApGfYS--
```

So it looks like all data is sent.

Comment: i was change to multipart/mixed, but still cannot this is my php code:

$gambar=$_FILES['gambar']['name'];
if(count($gambar)>0)
        {
            foreach($gambar as $key_gambar=>$val_gambar)
            {
                echo $key_gambar.":".$val_gambar;}}
if i submit more than one file, the output only one file. For example i submit image1.jpg, image2.jpg, image3.jpg when i submit, the output: 1:image1.jpg

Comment: leave it as "multipart/form-data".. if you are using PHP on the server, check out http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.multiple.php

Comment: i was change to multipart/form-data and  position the <table> into inside the <form>, like this: <form action='/add_save/' method='post' enctype='multipart/form-data'><table><tr>.....</tr></table></form>
 <br/> and all of gambar[] can be submitted. Thank you for helping me.. :)

Comment: Upvoted for putting such an effort into a poorly asked question.